# Trying to learn look aheads and look behinds

Tags: regex, perl

I've set up a simple test to test just the word 'Home' after a / in a URL. I have it working without the look aheads/behinds, but would like to use those to do the same thing.

```
my $page = "/Home"; #should 'match'
#or
$page = "/New Homes"; #should 'no match'

#A
if ($page =~ /Home | Home/) {
    print "no match A";
} else {
    print "match A";
}
print "\n\n";

#B
if ($page =~ /(?<= )Home(?= )/) {
    print "no match B";
} else {
    print "match B";
}
```

Returns:

```
no match A
match B #incorrect
```

So what am I not getting?

Comment: I hope you have `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your program?

Comment: It looks to me like your #A match is backwards.  It is `/Home | Home/`, which matches "Home" with a blank space just before or after it.  Then, your if statement prints "no match A" if there is a match.  I think you want your regex to be like `/Home\/|\/Home/` (or change the delimiters like `m!Home/|/Home!`) and make your if/else the other way around.  Your #B if statement is also done the same way (but see Nick's answer).

Answer (score 2):

In your example:

```
(?<= )Home(?= )
```

What you are doing here is search for an empty space (or whitespace) before and after home.  You want to put your search string inside the parenthesis. To search for the `/` before `home` use this:

```
(?<=\/)Home
```

Also, just as a note, with the look-aheads and look-behinds, they will not be returned as a match, they are just used to find the match.  So in the example above, `Home` would be returned as a match, not `/Home`.

Note: As was pointed out in the comments, perl requires the `/` to be escaped. I edited the code to contain an escaped `/`.

Comment: You should probably escape the `/` or note that a different delimiter should be used.

Comment: Unless it has something to do with perl, the `/` isn't on the list of [Special Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) that needs escaped.

Comment: It does have something to do with Perl, because (as you can see in the OP's code) regex literals are by default delimited using slashes. So if you don't escape the slash, it ends the regex. Either choose other delimiters or escape the slash ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think those two patterns are equivalent.

```
/(?<= )Home(?= )/
```

matches the same strings as

```
/ Home /
```

without including the spaces in the match, and

```
/Home(?= )|(?<= )Home/
```

matches the same strings as

```
/Home | Home/
```

without including the spaces in the match.

---

You probably want:

```
m{(?<![^/])Home(?![^/])}
```

It's similar to

```
m{(?<=/)Home(?=/)}
```

except `(?<![^/])` also matches at the beginning of the string, and `(?![^/])` also matches at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing me, and probably you as well.

This

```
my $page = "\/Home"; #should 'match'
#or
$page = "\/New Homes"; #should 'no match'
```

is equivalent to

```
my $page = '/New Homes';
```

as there is no need to escape a slash in a literal string, and no need to use double quotes unless you need interpolation of variables.

Also this

```
if ($page =~ /Home | Home/) {
    print "no match A";
} else {
    print "match A";
}
```

Is printing `no match A` when there is a match, and vice-versa, so your output of `no match A` is correct as `' Home'` *does* appear in `$page`.

The condition you are worried about

```
if ($page =~ /(?<= )Home(?= )/) {
    print "no match B";
} else {
    print "match B";
}
```

has the same problem, that it prints `no match B` when there is a match. It is looking for `Home`, preceded and followed by a space. `$page` contains `'/New Homes'` which has `'Home'` preceded, but not followed by a space. So it says `match B` because there is no match.

Try this variant of your program, correcting the sense of `match` and `no match` and adding `use strict` and `use warnings`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $page = '/New Homes';

if ($page =~ /Home | Home/) {
  print 'match A';
}
else {
  print 'no match A';
}

print "\n\n";

if ($page =~ /(?<= )Home(?= )/) {
  print 'match B';
}
else {
  print 'no match B';
}
```

**output**

```
match A

no match B
```